# And so a QVariant instantiation silently registeres a (previously declared) metatype

Tags: qt, qvariant

Take this program (adapted from an exploratory test-case, where I noticed that a custom metatype bahaves as if it was registered, although `qRegisterMetaType` had not been called):

```
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QVariant>

#include <iostream>

class C1 {
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(C1)


int main() {
    std::cout << QMetaType::type("C1") << std::endl;

    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue<C1>(C1());

    std::cout << QMetaType::type("C1") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
0
256
```

(and further tests do show that the metatype is indeed registered -- it can be `construct`'ed (even in places where `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(..)` is not visible), etc)

Is this behaviour well-known? Relied on? (Probably not, but attempting to get a failing test following the "official" rule to register a metatype first got me puzzled, hence the question)

P.S. Of course, one can see `qRegisterMetaType` called within `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(..)`, but the question still holds (at least I would like it to).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` doesn't call `qRegisterMetaType`, it defines a function that does. But `QVariant::fromValue<C1>` calls `qRegisterMetaType` indirectly, by calling the previously defined function.

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#details) suggests that calling `qRegisterMetaType` is only needed for things like queued connections.

Which means that you don't need to call `qRegisterMetaType` before using `QVariant` template functions for your type (but `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` has to be called in each compilation unit where those template functions are used or the compilation will fail).